# Pasing A KeyValuePair In A For Loop

Tags: vb.net

How do I pass an entire KeyValuePair to a For Loop?

```
 Dim grouped As New Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()
    For index = grouped.Count-1 To 0 Step -1

    'How do I pass the entire KeyValuePair to the PopulateData function?
    PopulateData(????)
    Next
```

Comment: What is the type of your `grouped` variable?

Comment: Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()

Comment: you need to go back to `For Each kvp As KeyValuePair...` if you want to pass a KVP.  But the method should logically only care about the `List(of DataRow)` ie the Value part

Comment: I cant iterate backwards through foreach

Comment: The order of items in a dictionary is unspecified, so it doesn't make sense to iterate forward or backwards through them. Depending on what your ordering needs are, `SortedDictionary` or `OrderedDictionary` might make more sense.

Comment: why do you need to iterate backwards? wouldn't a simple grouped.orderby(function(x)x.key) work? OR you could use an sortedlist(of keyvaluepair(of (string),list(of datarow))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, for example:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim grouped As New Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()
  For index = grouped.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    PopulateData(New KeyValuePair(Of String,
      List(Of DataRow))(grouped.Keys(index), grouped.Values(index)))
  Next
End Sub

Sub PopulateData(kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of DataRow)))
End Sub
```

However, you are stretching .NET framework to the limits this way, dictionary is not supposed to be iterated forwards or backwards. Even if you decide to iterate it, your code should not rely on order of the elements, or it may break later.

Comment: Im not relying on the order, my data got grouped first in last for some reason and as preference I want to iterate through and output the order in which the input was

Comment: I am using the Dictionary to seperate flat data into groups

Comment: `my data got grouped first in last for some reason` how can you know how it is grouped in the dictionary??? it has no set, specified order! @NickLaMarca

Comment: @NickLaMarca: `Im not relying on the order` why iterate backwards then?